# Permission for Ownership Changes

Tags: leads, ownership

Is it possible to raise the permissions on the change Owner function so that sales reps can not change the owner of an account that is in their name?

Answer (score 2):

If it is a single record being updated you can write a validation rule to disallow specific profiles from updating the owner.

```
AND(
  ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
  PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) = $User.Id, /*was the user the old owner?*/
  $Profile.Name = 'Sales Rep Profile'
)
```